# Error in RefineryCMS deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, capistrano3

Good morning.

I have a problem to upload on DigitalOcean my website. I use Capistrano 3. This is my *deploy.rb*:

```
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'polislegnano'
set :deploy_user, 'deployer'

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:MarcoSantino/polislegnano.git'

# Setup rbenv
set :rbenv_type, :system
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.0.0-p481'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rb\env_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5

# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

set :tests, []

set(:config_files, %w(
  nginx.conf
  database.example.yml
  log_rotation
  monit
  unicorn.rb
  unicorn_init.sh
))

set(:executable_config_files, %w(
  unicorn_init.sh
))

set(:symlinks, [
  {
    source: "nginx.conf",
    link: "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{full_app_name}"
  }
  {
    source: "unicorn_init.sh"
    link: "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{full_app_name}"
  }
  {
    source: "log_rotation"
    link: "/etc/logrotate.d/#{full_app_name}"
  }
  {
    source: "monit"
    link: "/etc/monit/conf.d/#{full_app_name}.conf"
  }
])
namespace :deploy do
  before :deploy, "deploy:check_revision"
  before :deploy, "deploy:run_tests"
  after 'deploy:symlinks:shared', 'deploy:compile_assets_locally'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

  before 'deploy:setup_config', 'nginx:remove_default_vhost'
  after 'deploy:setup_config', 'nginx:reload'
  after 'deploy:setup_config', 'nginx:restart'
  after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
end
```

When I run the command 'cap production deploy' in the terminal, it gives me this error:

```
cap aborted!
SyntaxError: config/deploy.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'
...th)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rb\env_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_pat...
...                               ^
config/deploy.rb:45: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_DEND, expecting '}'
config/deploy.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'
    link: "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{full_app_name}"
        ^
config/deploy.rb:51: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
    source: "log_rotation"
                         ^

Tasks: TOP => production
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried to rewrite the code from scratch twice, but I got the same error.

Does anyone known why?

Answer (score 0):

You have a \e in the fetch(:rbenv_ruby) call where you are setting the RBENV_VERSION on line 14.

Try taking out the backslash. That looks like a typo.